# Simple Change localStorage Name Prompt Doesn't Show

Tags: javascript

I'm learning basic localStorage [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#Adding_a_personalized_welcome_message)

Problem: I'm supposed to be able to change my stored name every time I click the Change User button

`https://jsfiddle.net/19bvwypn/`

```
var myButton = document.querySelector('button');    
var myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');

function setUserName() {
  var myName = prompt('Please enter your name.');
  localStorage.setItem('name', myName);
  myHeading.innerHTML = 'Mozilla is cool, ' + myName;
}

if(!localStorage.getItem('name')) {
  setUserName();
} else {
  var storedName = localStorage.getItem('name');
  myHeading.innerHTML = 'Mozilla is cool, ' + storedName;
}

myButton.onclick = function() {
  setUserName();
}
```

But nothing happens.
It works fine on Mozilla's own example site:
[link](https://mdn.github.io/beginner-html-site-scripted/)

Can someone tell me what I'm overlooking here? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Capax your code is 100% working, but you have forgot to add `h1` in your `HTML`, just add `<h1></h1>` after the `button`. Then there will be no issue in your fiddle. :)

Here is **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/19bvwypn/1/)**

**Thanks**